# Playing HLS stream in ionic

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html

I am trying to play a HLS stream in ionic angularjs, I put the hls stream into a iframe like so:

```
<iframe ng-src="http://barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/barakyah-channel/live/hottestjamsaudio/playlist.m3u8" seamless="seamless" scrolling="no" frameBorder="0" width="100%" height="100%" ></iframe>
```

i had read this method online.

instead of playing it it ask me to download the playlist for some reason it does not work.

i also tried using an HTML5 audio player using viblast:

```
<audio id="player" src="http://barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/barakyah-channel/live/hottestjamsaudio/playlist.m3u8" data-viblast-key="N8FjNTQ3NDdhZqZhNGI5NWU5ZTI=" controls></audio>
```

and i tried one other solution:

```
<button class="button" ng-click="play('http://barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/barakyah-channel/live/hottestjamsaudio/playlist.m3u8')">Play from file system</button>
```

JS for this solution:

```
 $scope.play = function(src) {
        var media = new Media(src, null, null, mediaStatusCallback);
        media.play(media);
    }

    var mediaStatusCallback = function(status) {
        if(status == 1) {
            $ionicLoading.show({template: 'Loading...'});
        } else {
            $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
    }
```

none of these worked.
I also tested it on a android device and it still did not work.

I get no errors it just does not play it asked me to download some playlist thing (it pulls up a where to save box)

Please help 
Thank you

Comment: Please specify what doens't work. Do you get any errors?

Comment: i have specifyed @RubenSteins

Comment: "I get no errors it just does not play it asked me to download some playlist thing(it pulls up a where to save box)" @RubenSteins

Comment: just put your link to your m3u8 stream and your android user will decide with that player he want to open it

Comment: i did this: <a href="http://barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/barakyah-channel/live/hottestjamsaudio/playlist.m3u8" class="button button-primary">Link</a> @DionisL

Comment: Yes , it must work for all users

Comment: @DionisL can you please post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your MIME-Type is application/vnd.apple.mpegurl, as output by wget

```
$ wget http://barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/barakyah-channel/live/hottestjamsaudio/playlist.m3u8
--2017-04-10 11:06:25--  http://barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net/barakyah-channel/live/hottestjamsaudio/playlist.m3u8
Resolving barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net... 173.208.17.141
Connecting to barakyah-channel.videocdn.scaleengine.net|173.208.17.141|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 107 [application/vnd.apple.mpegurl]
Saving to: ‘playlist.m3u8.1’

playlist.m3u8     100%[===================>]     107  --.-KB/s    in 0s      

2017-04-10 11:06:27 (6.38 MB/s) - ‘playlist.m3u8’ saved [107/107]
```

Try to change it server-/cdn-side:

```
application/x-mpegurl m3u8;
video/mp2t ts;
application/xml xml;
```